# Adding a custom HTML bootstrap page to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

i would like to add a bootstrap html webpage to SharePoint online. 
like the one below.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oeaBdw

it has links to bootstrap css and js files is it possible to copy and past it directly to the script editor.

for some reason it is not working for me.

Comment: Look this article, how is this working:
<br>[Bootstrap and SharePoint Online](https://melcher.it/2016/03/bootstrap-sharepoint-online-avoid-css-ricochet/)

Comment: wow looks really complicated !

Answer (score 3):

Easier way to do this is create an HTML file with references to JS and CSS (as you already have). Add a `Content Editor Webpart(CEWP)` on the page where you want to display the HTML. Edit the CEWP and set the `Content Link` field with URL to the HTML page you created.

Answer (score 0):

In addition of Akshay's Answer. Convert your .html file to a .txt. Save it and all the referenced CSS and JS files into a document library (I would prefer Sites Assets library).

rest as Akshay said, give the file path of the .txt file in CEWP.

(I don't know why but when I give link of an HTML file in CEWP, it take a bit more time then .txt)

And I would suggest, instead of putting all the content with in the HTML file, fetch the data from a list by CAML query.

Comment: While using the bootstrap the some of the elements such as fonts and headings in the ribbon  etc changed. is there anything i have to do to make them the way it is

Comment: Try with **!important**